# VS 2010 Floating code window NOT always on top

Tags: ide, visual-studio-2010, environment

Most of the time when I code, either using Visual Studio or gVim, I like to have many open windows with code files so that I can go back and forth from one to another, either to edit or just read while editing another file.

Thus I found VS 2010's feature of "floating" code windows very helpful. However, the fact that when a code window is floating, it's "*always on top*" is a bit annoying, because it might hide other windows, such as the "Find Results" for example.

Is this something that is customizable? Is there a configuration value somewhere that either enables or disables the "always on top feature" of floating code windows in Visual Studio 2010?

Thanks

Comment: I think this should be migrated to SuperUser since it is quite specific to an IDE.

Comment: I migrated this here, rather than Super User as I thought it would be more likely to get answers. It was a tough call though.

Comment: @ChrisF Yeah I know, I wasn't quite sure where to post this in the first place.

Comment: don't worry about it. It's what the migration paths or ultimately the mod tools are there for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is not a real top-most window, it is merely on top of the Visual Studio main window.  An 'owned' window.  From where it competes with other windows that VS displays for the Z-order, like the Find Results window.  You'd need to arrange these windows so they don't easily overlap and obscure each other.  That's supported, you can dock them.  Bit of a chicken-and-egg problem, isn't it?

If you have concrete ideas how to improve this then you can post them to connect.microsoft.com

Comment: Perhaps not the answer I was hoping for, but an answer indeed. I suppose that a solution of assigning the proper z-order on each window getting focus could work, but I have no specifics yet to elaborate upon. Thanks anyway.